# read page by page of docx file in VC# 2010

Tags: c#, docx

I have been using the following code to read the entire word document.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
                //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordObject = new ApplicationClass();
                object file = file_path.Text; //this is the path
                object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open
                    (ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject,
                    ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject
                                    );

                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();                
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
                IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                //docx_contents.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                pages = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
```

I'm getting everything in pages variable. Please suggest me how can I read page by page in array of string?

Answer (score 0):

it is part of my codes

```
        DOCXStructure[] returnval = null;

        object file = filePath;
        object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object read_only = true;

        wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
        fileName = "~" + fileName;




        document = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);



        Word.WdStatistic stat = Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
        int PageNum = document.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref nullobj);

        returnval = new DOCXStructure[PageNum];

        for(int i=0; i<PageNum; i++){
            returnval[i] = new DOCXStructure();

            object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
            object which = nullobj;
            object count = i+1;
            object name = nullobj;
            object Page = "\\Page";

            wordApp.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref name);

            Word.Range range = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Page).Range;
            returnval[i].page = i+1;
            returnval[i].context.AddRange(range.Text.Split('\r', '\n', '\t'));
        }
        document.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```